# Fast Poisson Solver Question (PDEs)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm working on this question:

> $(2)$ Solve the two-dimensional Poisson problem
>   $$\Delta u+\lambda u=f\quad\text{in}\quad\Omega=(0,1)^2$$
>   subject to homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions using a fast Poisson solver. You will have to adjust the code $\mathtt{fastpoissonD2d.m}$ and you have to turn in a hardcopy of your code. In addition, apply your code to the specific problem $\lambda=100$ and $f(x,y)=-2x+3y$, and include images of the solution $u$ for discretization sizes $N=128$ and $N=256$.

I've worked through most of the problem.  The issue I'm having is that the code we're given is for u'' = -1.  I have no idea how to incorporate the u and the eigenvalue into the solver, although I have incorporated the given function.

> My question is there is this bit of code: Leig  = (((2*cos(pi*(1:N-1)'/N))-2)*ones(1,N-1)) + ...
>            (ones(N-1,1)*((2*cos(pi*(1:N-1)/N))-2));  I have no what this does, perhaps it would answer my question.  If someone could join me in http://collabedit.com/qt5c8 and we could converse about the code together?

Comment: Hi, Bob, maybe this question will get better answer at [scicomp.SE].

Comment: Where can we see $\mathtt{fastpoissonD2d.m}$?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao: after we make the question into a good question, we can think about migrating it.

Comment: @robjohn Makes sense. Now I am inclining not migrating it. For this is apparently a numerical pde class project which is supposed to be done by the student himself. Provided you have the code $\mathtt{fastpoissonD2d.m}$.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao: I believe you are correct. This is part of the reason it is best to have all of a question local; we know what it asks without having to look elsewhere.